# particular case of Pythagoras' theorem

Tags: geometry

According to Pythagoras' theorem the hypotenuse of a rectangle triangle is calculated:
$$c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$ 
There is a similar rectangle triangle that fulfills: 
$$C^2=A+B$$
For it: 
1) We find the relation of the legs:
$r={a\over b}$

2) We raise r squared and calculate:
$d={1\over r^2+1}$

3) We obtain a first triangle similar to d, e, f with less leg equal to d, and e, greater leg:
$e=dr$

4) We obtain a second triangle also similar g, h, i where:
$g=e$ and $h=1−d$

5) Now we add the minor and major legs of d, e, f and h, i, j to obtain the ABC triangle:
$A=d+e$ and $B=h+e$

6) This ABC triangle complies with:
$C=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}=\sqrt{A+B}$

This I have checked in all tests, but I could not make a demonstration. 
Note that the calculated C hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the sines of the angles of the triangle not straight.

Comment: Please take a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to learn how to format your text.

Comment: Pythagoras' theorem is $c^2=a^2+b^2$, so $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, not $c^2$

Comment: This is confusing: $C^2=\sqrt{A+B}$ .... $A, B$ are not squared?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean, since you've got Pythagoras's theorem wrong.  Please try to restate your question.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes, I'm not used to the editor. I fixed it. I think

Comment: A and B are areas of triangle? Or values of length?

Comment: Values of length.

Comment: So they need to be squared. But above all, what is the question??

Comment: Are $c$ and $C$ (and $a$ and $A$, etc) the same thing? Note that $a=b=1$ and $c=\sqrt{2}$ satisfy $c^2 = a^2+b^2=a+b$.

Comment: @Blue I have taken into account the equations a = A, b = B and c = C and edited the expression C=√{A2+B2}=√{A+B} thanks. The solution A = 1, B = 1 C=√2 corresponds to the triangles where a = b this is isosceles rectangles, C=√2=2sin45 . Other triangles give non-integer solutions for example a = 3, b = 4 results in A = 0.84 B = 1.12 and C = 1.4 and thus any value of a and b that is proposed. The values of C will be between 1 for value of a=0 or b = 0 and √2 for values of a = b and will correspond to the sum of the sines of the angles.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question can be simplified to find particular cases of $$\sqrt{A^2+B^2}=\sqrt{A+B}$$ We can square both sides and move $A$ and $B^2$ to their other sides, getting $$A^2-A=B-B^2$$ If we replace $B-B^2$ with $C$ then we can create the quadratic equation $$A^2-A-C=0$$ and using the quadratic formula and replacing $C$ we obtain $$A=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4(B-B^2)}}2$$

Comment: Consider A = 0.84 and b = 1.12 (values obtained for the relation of legs $4\over3$) $$A^2-A = -0.1344$$ and $$ B^2-B = 0.1344$$ Then the equality $$A^2-A=B^2-B $$ is not met.  On the other hand, if you do it using $$A^2-A = B-B^2$$

Comment: @user167434 Thanks for spotting that error there. Yes, it should be $A^2-A=B-B^2$ than the other way around.